# TypeError: g.join is not a function in queryTask.execute

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to query data from a server, so I try to exploit ["Query data without a map"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_nomap.html) sample. However, at `queryTask.execute` I get following error:

```
TypeError: g.join is not a function
```

My code is similar to that in the example:

```
var queryTask = new QueryTask(featureClassUrl);

var query = new Query();
query.f = "json";
query.outFields = "*";
query.returnGeometry = true;
query.where = "Foo = 'Bar'";

$(document).submit(function (e) {
    queryTask.execute(query, updateResults);
});

function updateResults(results) {
    //working with the results
}
```

The only significant difference from the example is in the event listener. Does JQuery or submit event really break it?

The closest to my question what I found is [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24979256/1801588), but I failed to apply the solution for `on` to `queryTask.execute`.

I use JavaScript API v. 3.14.

Comment: What version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query.outFields` must be an [array of strings](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#outfields), so you should rewrite that line to be:

```
query.outFields = ["*"];
```